# How to get a pointer of list?

Tags: c#, unmanaged

So i know that list holds array inside it, so i need to get a pointer of unknown type of it (void*). It is pretty easy to do with arrays:

```
int[] items;
fixed (void* pointer = items)
{

}
```

So i need to do same thing for List

```
List<int> items;
fixed (void* pointer = items)
{

}
```

This code doesn't seems to work. I don't want to copy a list to a new array, i want to access a pointer to it's internal array

Comment: Don't ask me, why i need to use unmanaged code. I just need to

Comment: You could get a pointer to its first item, since thats essentially what you are doing with an array.

Comment: @RonBeyer but i can do that only if my List contains value types, right?

Comment: Yes, but in the case you are using reference types, you could always get the list as an array `items.ToArray()`.

Comment: @RonBeyer items.ToArray() creates a new array, which drops a performance

Comment: @Eugen1344 You cannot get a pointer to a `List<T>` in C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It IS possible.

1. You can access the private array filed `List<T>._items` by reflection.
2. Implement one yourself!

   Take advantage of the open-sourced .NET Core project, it's free: [source code of `List<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs). Then adding methods or something to get a unsafe pointer of `List<T>._items` is very easy.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to get a pointer to a `List<T>` - you can only get pointers to arrays of primitive types. (In that case, you get a pointer to the first element by getting its address.)

Depending on how big your list is, you can call `ToArray()` on the list and then get a pointer to the first element but this could be fairly expensive for large arrays.

Comment: ok, so maybe there is a way to get Array from list without copying it?

Comment: @Eugen1344 Not that I know of. C++/CLI _may_ have a way to do that but I'm unsure.